# Cannot convert expression type 'Dictionary' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, xcode6.1

I'm trying to create a dictionary in swift but am getting an error. I tried unwrapping the variable to by adding a '?'. Not sure what the correct way to create a dictionary

```
class Event: NSObject {

// When I remove the '?' on the variables it works but im not quite sure why
// Should I not be declaring variable as optional unwrapped?

var title:String?
var eventDescription:String?
var duration:Double?
var eventID:String?
var hostID:String?
var location:CLLocation?
var category:String?
var invitedUsers:[String?]

func createEvent(){

    // setting up event information to save
    var postEventData = [
        "title": self.title,
        "description":self.eventDescription,
        "duration":self.duration,
        "host":self.hostID,
        "category":self.category
    ]

}
func setTitle(title:String?){
    self.title = title
}

func setEventDescription(eventDescription:String?){
    self.eventDescription = eventDescription
}
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you say that `title` (and the other properties) may or may not have a value:

```
var title:String?
```

Then here you try to use the value of `title`:

```
var postEventData = [
    "title": self.title,
    "description":self.eventDescription,
    "duration":self.duration,
    "host":self.hostID,
    "category":self.category
]
```

You need to decide what you want to do if `title` does not have a value. Should `postEventData` be created? Should it use defaults? In theory you could create a dictionary of `[String : String?]`, but that's generally not useful (since fetching values from dictionaries already returns an optional).

So you have several options here, depending on what you want for this data structure.

- Make your properties non-optional. Is it actually ok for these properties to have no value? Perhaps they should default to `""` rather than be optional.
- Only allow `createEvent()` if all the properties are set (I've rewritten `createEvent` to return a value because your current code just creates a variable and then throws it away, so I wasn't certain what the goal was):

---

```
func createEvent() -> [String: String] {
    if let title = self.title,
           description = self.eventDescription,
           duration = self.duration, 
           host = self.hostID,
           category = self.category {
        return [
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "duration": duration,
            "host": host,
            "category": category
         ]
     }
     return nil
 }
```

---

- Use default values if properties aren't set:

---

```
func createEvent() -> [String: String] {
    return [
        "title": self.title ?? "", 
        "description": self.eventDescription ?? "",
        "duration": self.duration ?? "",
        "host": self.hostID ?? "",
        "category": self.category ?? ""
    ]
}
```

- Or ask yourself why you're creating a dictionary. You already have a data structure for this; do you really need to convert it?

As a side note, there is no reason for your `set...` methods. A prefix of `set` has special meaning in Swift. The caller should just say `event.title = ...`. If you need some kind of special setter handling, use a `set` option to define it on your property.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, very concise and clear.

Comment: Does "title": self.title ?? "", unwrap self.titles value if its declared as 'String?'

Comment: Yes, but it's better to think of it as takes the value of self.title if there is one, otherwise takes the value of the next operand. I think people get way too wrapped up in "unwrapping."

Comment: I agree, optional values have been a area of confusion for me. For example, what is the difference between title:String = "Title" ; title:String? = "Title" ; title:String! = "Title"?

Comment: `String` is a value. `String?` is an optional value (it may or may not have a value). `String!` is a piece of low-level craziness to make it slightly easier to work with Cocoa interfaces that haven't yet been audited. You should avoid it whenever possible, and every release of Swift has reduced how often you need it, and some day it should mostly go away. So your first has a value. Your second might have a value. And your third says "this is supposed to have a value, and so you can pretend like it does, and if it turns out it doesn't, we'll crash."

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it does not let you use it that way because a type with '?' means it is optional so it can be unsafe because of the possibilty of a nil inside. 
You should check these properties against nil first and explicitly or implicitly unwrap them for later use in a dictionary.

```
...
var category:String?

if let cat = self.category? {

    // setting up event information to save
    var postEventData = [
        "category":cat
    ]
 }
```

In my example you can see I made only category an optional, then unwrapped it and used in your dictionary. It works fine as no nil value will ever get inside under "category" key.

Fixed for clearer understanding.

Comment: Do I need to do that for all the variables? It seems weird to only have to do that for 1 of them.

Comment: Yes, you have to check every one of them. I just gave an example on one variable.

Comment: Why do you set the rest of them along with the 1 variable that you checked? Wouldn't you just overwrite them if you hadn't checked them?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need an initialiser for the non-optional properties, and second, Swift dictionaries need need to have all keys and values of the same specific type.

```
class Event: NSObject {

    // When I remove the '?' on the variables it works but im not quite sure why
    // Should I not be declaring variable as optional unwrapped?

    // initialiser because of non-optional property
    override init() {
        self.invitedUsers = []
    }

    var title:String?
    var eventDescription:String?
    var duration:Double?
    var eventID:String?
    var hostID:String?
    var category:String?
    var invitedUsers:[String?]

    func createEvent(){

        // setting up event information to save
        // explicitly set the values types as Any
        var postEventData : Dictionary<String, Any> = [
            "title": self.title,
            "description":self.eventDescription,
            "duration":self.duration,
            "host":self.hostID,
            "category":self.category
        ]
    }
}
```